# Meteor Group Collection by Field

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I am trying to return a collection (Postings) grouped by a field (status).  I am pretty new to mongo and meteor. The query below gives me the collections grouped by status with # of docs by that status... basically I want the same thing but have the actual documents in there.

Also, I would like to be able to publish/subscribe to this so that they reactivly update.  I am creating an admin dashboard that groups all the Postings by current status.

A friend provided the following gist, but it is a bit over my head: https://gist.github.com/ryw/8827179

```
db.postings.group({ key: {status: 1}, initial: {sum:0}, reduce: function(doc, prev) { prev.sum += 1; } })
```

Thanks!

Comment: So does the admin dashboard need to show the all of the postings, or does it need to show a summary of the postings (count by status)? I'm unclear if you actually need all of the documents on the client or not

Comment: It needs to have the documents, not the count.

Answer (score 1):

If you need all of the documents on the client, then I would just publish the whole collection and let the template code group them.

#### client

```js
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Meteor.subscribe('allPostings');
  }
});

Template.admin.helpers({
  postings: function() {
    if (Session.get('currentStatus')) {
      return Postings.find({status: Session.get('currentStatus')});
    }
  },
  statuses: function() {
    return _.uniq(_.pluck(Postings.find().fetch(), 'status'));
  }
});

Template.admin.events({
  'click .status': function() {
    Session.set('currentStatus', String(this));
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="admin">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <ul>
      {{#each statuses}}
      <li class="status">{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel">
    <ul>
      {{#each postings}}
      <li>{{message}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### server

```js
Meteor.publish('allPostings', function() {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  if (user.isAdmin) {
    return Postings.find();
  }
});
```

I'm assuming you have some way to identify admin users (here I used `isAdmin`). I am also assuming that a posting has a `status` and a `message`.

Comment: How can they be grouped by status.  Am looking to do something like this: http://goo.gl/vqXSHi where documents are grouped under each status header.

Comment: You can use a session variable to track the current status, and use that to filter which postings to show. I rewrote the answer with this in mind.

Comment: @DavidWeldon, Quick security note, the `user.profile` field is editable by default so to make this example secure you would need to keep your `isAdmin` field on the user object itself:  `user.isAdmin`.

Comment: @alanning Thanks Adrian. I updated the example to assume `isAdmin` is on the user object and only examined on the server. Note to other readers - you could use [roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) to accomplish this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using aggregate functions or map reduce operations, you could denormalize your data and store a separate collection of the groups and their counts.

You can update your counts using observe functions as in the following example from the [relevant section](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes) of meteor docs:

```
// Keep track of how many administrators are online.
var count = 0;
var query = Users.find({admin: true, onlineNow: true});
var handle = query.observeChanges({
  added: function (id, user) {
    count++;
    console.log(user.name + " brings the total to " + count + " admins.");
  },
  removed: function () {
    count--;
    console.log("Lost one. We're now down to " + count + " admins.");
  }
});

// After five seconds, stop keeping the count.
setTimeout(function () {handle.stop();}, 5000);
```

This way, you can present the groups and their counts on a template and it would be reactive.